# How to find exact value using xpath in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using `XPath` to find exact value:

`//h5[@class='familyName productFamilyName'][contains(text(),'Dozers ')]`

but it was failing because in my application there are 2 elements with text values `"Dozers "` and `"Dozers wheel"` which is come under same class.
I can't use id locators,because it is dynamically generating in my application like `//div[@id="482"]/div/div[1]/h5`.

Please suggest me any solution.

Comment: You should provide `HTML` code for two mentioned elements so we can suggest more specific solution

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match element with exact `innerHTML` value just use

```
//h5[@class='familyName productFamilyName'][text()='Dozers')]
```

or

```
//h5[@class='familyName productFamilyName'][text()='Dozers wheel')]
```

Depending on `HTML` structure you might need to use `[.='Dozers']` or

`[normalize-space(.)='Dozers']` instead of `[text()='Dozers']`

Comment: Thanks @andersson. Both solution you have mentioned are working for me.

Comment: @user3161030, please do mark this as answer then :)